# Comment added by webservice not visible in front end

Tags: magento-1.9, api, sales-order

I'm using the magento version 1.9.2.4 with its webservice wsdl, i'm adding comments in my request using the webservice's method with java:

```
proxy.salesOrderAddComment(session, "100000019", "Processando", "adicionado o status 11", null);
```

The same is showed in admin panel, but no showed in front end:

[image]

If i add by admin panel with checkbox "is_visible_on_front" is showed, my question is how enable this with the webservices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the default API method to add comment does not support the `is_visible_on_front` parameter.

So you'll need a custom module for that.

`app/etc/modules/DigitalPianism_ExtendedApi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DigitalPianism_ExtendedApi>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Api />
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </DigitalPianism_ExtendedApi>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/DigitalPianism/ExtendedApi/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DigitalPianism_ExtendedApi>
            <version>0.0.10</version>
        </DigitalPianism_ExtendedApi>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_api>DigitalPianism_ExtendedApi_Model_Sales_Order_Api</order_api>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/DigitalPianism/ExtendedApi/Model/Sales/Order/Api.php`

In this file we are going to rewrite the method to handle this parameter the visibility parameter:

```
<?php

class DigitalPianism_ExtendedApi extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api
{

    public function addComment($orderIncrementId, $status, $comment = '', $notify = false, $visible = false)
    {
        $order = $this->_initOrder($orderIncrementId);

        $historyItem = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, $status);
        $historyItem->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible);
        $historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified($notify)->save();


        try {
            if ($notify && $comment) {
                $oldStore = Mage::getDesign()->getStore();
                $oldArea = Mage::getDesign()->getArea();
                Mage::getDesign()->setStore($order->getStoreId());
                Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend');
            }

            $order->save();
            $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify, $comment);
            if ($notify && $comment) {
                Mage::getDesign()->setStore($oldStore);
                Mage::getDesign()->setArea($oldArea);
            }

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('status_not_changed', $e->getMessage());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use an extra parameter in the API call to set that visible parameter to true:

```
proxy.salesOrderAddComment(session, "100000019", "Processando", "adicionado o status 11", null, true);
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. When you say to rewrite the method, you wanna say rewrite in magento API or override the method with java ? thaks

Comment: @Brunno I've pasted the code of the custom module you will need to implement this functionality